# Netbeans and Derby : access denied

Tags: netbeans, derby

I have just downloaded and installed Netbeans 7.2.1. Goind on the service tab and trying to start JavaDB. I have the following error :

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "file.encoding" "read")
```

:(

a problem Java Security Manager

Can someone tell me how to resolve this to finally start javaDB by right clicking and choose "Start server" ?

Thank you

Comment: this is it.. can you put the link like your answer so I can accept it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this , You need to append this permission below to the java policy file that is shipped with JDK 1.7.:

```
permission java.util.PropertyPermission "file.encoding", "read";
```

The file can be found under :  ***/jdk1.7.0/jre/lib/security/java.policy***

Visit [this](http://hanynowsky.wordpress.com/2012/05/03/oracle-sun-jdk-7-derby-server-java-db-does-not-start-using-glassfish-3-1-2-in-netbeans-7-1-2-permission-denied/) link for more information. You can check this [IBM document](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.base.doc%2Finfo%2Faes%2Fae%2Frsec_javapolicy.html) for configuration file descriptions.

Answer (score 1):

I found a quick solution to this problem - Start your JavaDB from the command line\terminal like so:

```
<base folder>/db/bin/startNetworkServer -noSecurityManager
```

Then it runs fine without adding new permissions.